# Upload file from another storage to Amazon S3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, google-drive-api

How to download file to Amazon S3 from Google Drive for example?

I already have working code that upload some image to Amazon, but in this case i already now type of image. In case of Google Drive - i just have link without file extension. File types, that are allowed in my case, are .pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx